# ImageView. Подгон размера картинки

Tags: изображения, android, ui

Вот есть какой то ImageView занимающий весь экран на девайсе, например, экран с размером 400x400, есть картинка, с размером 200x400, можно ли как то настроить ImageView в layout-файле, что бы он подогнал под свой размер, то есть увеличил картинку до 400x800, обрезал равномерно с краев до 400x400?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. ScaleType поставьте CENTER_CROP.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html